# How to solve open redirect vulnerability in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

We have a wordpress website and we conduct penetration test on it. Unfortunately we got a result that we are vulnerable in open redirects. how to fix this? I tried setting up whitelisting in our AWS ec2 instance we're the website was deployed. I'm still not sure if what is the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

What version of wordpress are you using?

Wordfence announced that [WordPress is vulnerable to open redirect in versions up to 6.0.31](https://www.wordfence.com/threat-intel/vulnerabilities/wordpress-core/wordpress-core-603-open-redirect).

You can try to upgrade your wordress core and try test again, if the problem were still exist, then deactivate your plugins, use WP default theme to find out which plugins/theme is cuasing the vulnerability